# Code refactoring SQL Server database object name change

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, refactoring

Is there a refactoring functionality which would make it easier to make simple database object name change easier in SQL Server?

I mean I just need to alter a name of a table and few columns, now these would be utilized in hundreds of different places. Is there an easier way than to go in manually and make the changes in hundreds of places?

I know in Visual Studio C# you can use the cool refactoring feature to do such a thing in .net technologies.

If there is one such thing. I can make a backup file of my database and would like to work with a .bak file

Comment: If you start using the SQL Server Data Tools projects in Visual Studio, you can do this

Answer (score 2):

RedGate is pricey but they have a function in SQL prompt called smart rename that will read all the locations in your database and create a script for you review and run. I have had to use it from time to time but it is a lifesaver.

Hope that helps,
Jason